# Batch Scripting iterating over files in a folder and extract for each one just the first line

Tags: batch-file, header, iteration

I need to iterate over files contained in a folder and extract the first line for each file. I've tried to get this writing two batch file - the first one overate over files:

```
FOR %%a in (D:\TEST_BAT\*.TXT) do (


call Estrai_Header.bat %%a %header%
@echo on
echo %header%


)
```

The second one (named `Estrai_header.bat`) extract the first line for the file (just passing it as parameter):

```
 set header = ""
 SET /A maxlines=1
 SET /A linecount=0

FOR /F %%b IN (%1) DO ( 


    IF !linecount! GEQ %maxlines% GOTO ExitLoop

    set $2 =  %2%%b 
    echo %2%
    SET /A linecount+=1
    echo %linecount%
)

:ExitLoop
exit /b
```

`Estrai_Header.bat` works correctly and prints for every file just the first row. But I cannot see the value of the first line extracted in the first batch (it prints a void string). What's wrong in these batch files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
FOR %%a in (D:\TEST_BAT\*.TXT) do (
set "line="
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("%%a") do if not defined line set "line=%%i"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo(!line!
endlocal
)
```